# Error while binding variables in NS-2

Tags: c++, tcl, ns2

I am using NS-2.35 ... I made changes to AODV protocol to support controlled mobility. I needed to pass x and y positions (after executing an algorithm for mobility) from C++ to TCL and then put them into (setdest) command.
I did the following in aodv constructor:

```html
  bind("x_axis",&x_tcl);
  bind("y_axis",&y_tcl);
```

and I gave x_axis and y-axis a default value in **ns-default.tcl**.

and this is how i use them in TCL code:

```html
$ns at 21.0 "$node_(0) setdest $x_axis $y_axis 100.0"
```

but I am getting the following error:

```html
num_nodes is set 36
warning: Please use -channel as shown in tcl/ex/wireless-mitf.tcl
INITIALIZE THE LIST xListHead
can't read "x_axis": no such variable
    while executing
"$ns at 21.0 "$node_(0) setdest $x_axis $y_axis 100.0""
    (file "eaodv.tcl" line 309)
```

Is there any problem?? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is in your usage of the binding variables in tcl

```
$ns at 21.0 "$node_(0) setdest x_axis y_axis 100.0"
```

This should help [OTcl Linkage](http://nile.wpi.edu/NS/linkage.html)